# Escaping in Sphinx

Tags: escaping, sphinx

I am trying to match a phrase in a document which unfortunately in the catalog I have is formatted like this:

```
Includes sides?** *No*
```

or

```
Includes sides?** *Yes*
```

searching for either one fails e.g.

```
Search idx_test where MATCH('"Includes sides?** *Yes*"')
```

If I search on

```
Search idx_test where MATCH('"Includes sides"')
```

it does not fail (but finds both)

and if I as a test change the data itself to:

```
Includes sides No
```

I can find it with Sphinx

```
Search idx_test where MATCH('"Includes sides No"')
```

So clearly the `?` and the `*` need to be escaped. Yet nothing I've done works e.g using `\*`

Answer (score 0):

Try.,.

```
...where MATCH('"Includes sides\\? \\*Yes\\*"')
```

Need multiple, one as you in a sql string, the second for the extended syntax query.

If you also writing it as a string in language like php, might need **more** quotes, to escape in php string.

Can also just remove them from query, they only syntax in querying so don't need to change data.

(Alough slightly more complicated if using `phrase_boundary`)

Comment: Starting here: `where MATCH('"Includes sides\\?"')` this does not return `work from home?` but it does return any `work from home` followed by a character e.g. `work from home_`.

Comment: In terms of removing from the query I did try `where MATCH('"Includes sides Yes"')` assuming they were never even indexed but that is a fail too. Hard to solve since in theory I could just do `Includes sides?` if it were any character BUT ?

Comment: For now I just did `"Includes Sides" !(("Includes  sides" NEAR/2 "No") ("Includes  sides" >> "No"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried a # of solutions that did not work:

1. I added regexp_ in the config to map `?=>qmark` and `*=>asterisk`. I had no luck with this regardless of how I searched i.e. `Includes sidesqmark` and `Includes sides qmark` (latter assuming ? treated as separate work
2. I commented the regexp back out and tried searching on `Includes Sides No` on the logic that `?` and `*` are not being indexed so those spaces don't exist.
3. I added spaced between `Includes sides` and `No` assuming that one or more of the chars was not indexing but somehow taking up a char space e.g. `Includes sides   No`.
4. I added double escapes as was suggested to me `"Includes sides\?\*\* \*No" which failed too.

None of these worked.

I tried doing NEAR/ and >> together and that worked:

```
("Includes sides" NEAR/2 "No") ("Includes sides" >> "No")
```

which seemed clunky.

Finally I did this which worked

```
"Includes sides \\*"No"
```

Which works but is a total mystery to me why though I am posting it since it solves the problem. I'm hoping someone else can explain the mechanisms behind this:

- Clearly the `\\` is the right way to escape in sphinxql
- Clearly escaping the asterisk is working
- Clearly escaping the `?` is not
- Yet if the asterisk needs to be escaped then how come:

`"Includes sides\\?\\*\\* \\*No`

does not work AND

`"Includes sides\\*\\* \\*No`

does not work? If it is not indexing/recognizing the `?` but clearly is the `*` then I'd need to escape the two after `Includes`. Yet it is as if neither the `?` nor the `*` after `Includes` exist BUT the `asterisk` before `No` does.

Sorry to include a question an answer yet my solution worked. If there is a better way for me to both provide the solution I used and the question that it revealed please let me know as I'm trying not to confuse the issue here.

Comment: Did you check if using `phrase_boundary`? if you have `?` in there, it would complicate phrase matches. Also check if ? and * are in charset_table. In your case would still recommend them NOT being in charset_table.